# Enable GL_INTEL_performance_query on Intel HD 500?

Tags: opengl

I am trying to use the OpenGL extension: GL_INTEL_performance_query to read the Intel performance counters from an integrated Intel GPU (HD 500). This extension is supported on my hardware and also available on OGL starting [OpenGL 3.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/INTEL/INTEL_performance_query.txt) When I run the following code snippet on my machine:

```
 if( !IsExtensionSupported("GL_INTEL_performance_query") )
    {
        printf( "ERROR: extension GL_INTEL_performance_query isn't available, exiting\n" );
        return false;
    }
```

I get an error that the extension is not supported. The current version for the OGL is:

```
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 128 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 19.0.8
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 7822MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
```

When I try to list all available extensions I get this list:

```
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2,
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters,
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil,
    GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object,
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp,
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color,
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap,
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D,
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map,
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3,
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias,
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object,
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode,
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm,
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback,
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra,
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip,
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate,
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_no_error,
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_pack_invert,
    GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba,
    GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, GL_NV_blend_square,
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fog_distance,
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil,
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_NV_texgen_reflection,
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image,
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap,
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp,
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays
```

Is there a way to enable a specific extension or any hints if the problem is related to OGL version vs Hardware?

Update:

1. I am running in a non-virtualized environment.
2. Host is: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: @genpfault are you sure about the linux tag ?

Comment: @Orace: As of OP's latest edit, yeah :)

Answer (score 1):

From your info :

```
Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)  // virtual machine
Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 128 bits) (0xffffffff) // Low-Level Virtual Machine pipe
Accelerated: no                    // no acceleration
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc. // virtual machine
```

It's looks like your OpenGl device is not an *Intel HD 500* but a virtual one (or you work on a virtual machine).

Try to update your video card driver and/or [activate accelerated 3D graphics in the virtual machine](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/12.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-F5186526-2382-4F4A-8009-3D07773A1404.html).

Comment: I am running in a non-virtualized environment with host Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Could it be that the OGL configurations is broken?

Comment: @KeithApe obviously you don't have the intel drivers installed / used

Comment: One last question, does using the linux machine remotely over ssh reconfigure the underlying used driver by any means? Or this is totally unrelated

Comment: totally related ! you don't have graphic by default while using SSH, so no 3d acceleration. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely
If you actually work via SSH (without use of -X), it's consistent to have a virtual graphic card.